# How can I have the navbar dropown always open for xs screen?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the code below to collapse the navigation bar when you click outside and inside the navigation bar for xs screen. The code work nice if you do not have dropdown menus. I have introduced dropdown menus and on my navbar so what happens is that the when your try to open the dropdown on small screens the navigation bar collapses. How can I have these dropdown list always open for xs screen and hide their parent links?

script to collapse navigation

```
    // Collase if Click Happened Inside of .navbar
    $('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function(){ 
        if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !=='none'){
            $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
        }
    });

    // Collase if Click Happened Outside of .navbar 
    $('body').bind('click', function(e) {
        if($(e.target).closest('.navbar').length === 0) {
            // click happened outside of .navbar, so hide
            var opened = jQuery('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('collapse in');
            if ( opened === true ) {
                $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            }
        }
    });
```

html code

```
    <!-- Navigation Bar --> 
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#page-top" title="Welcome" target="_self" class="navbar-brand page-scroll">Brand</a>

              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about" title="About US" target="_self" class="page-scroll">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" title="Our Services &amp; Skills" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000">
                            Services <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#services" title="OUR Services" target="_self" class="page-scroll">OUR Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#skills" title="Our Skills Chart" target="_self" class="page-scroll">OUR Skills Chart</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                        
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" title="Our Portfolio &amp; Testimonials" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000">
                            Portfolio <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#portfolio" title="Our Portfolio" target="_self" class="page-scroll">OUR Work</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#testimonials" title="Testimonials" target="_self" class="page-scroll">Testimonials</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#team" title="Our Team" target="_self" class="page-scroll">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact" title="Contact US" target="_self" class="page-scroll">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update event binding to handle Click Happened Inside of .navbar as below

```
// Collase if Click Happened Inside of .navbar
$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function(){ 
    if(!$(this).parent('.dropdown').length && $('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !=='none'){
        $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Here is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ye7z26Lx/2/